Running multi-tenant app (Tenancy for laravel) on laravel herd
I have a Laravel app using tenancy for laravel and i initially ran it using php artisan serve and the central domain was localhost:8000 and it worked fine but i recently installed laravel herd to use it as a local development server and i changed my central domain to tenancy.test but now i can't access subdomains but i can access central domain fine.
I tried reverting back to using php artisan serve but now i get this error  WARN  Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: ?)

Did you update your SESSION_DOMAIN in env? It should be SESSION_DOMAIN=.tenancy.test now

@zlatan thanks for the reply but that did help what worked is that i had to run this command herd link subdomain.domain
